# array calculation in python dot product of three arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python.
How can I do dot product of 3 arrays in python numpy.
I have three matrices

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[-1 -2 -3]
```

I want to do (1x4x(-1)) + (2x5x(-2)) + (3x6x(-3)) = -4-20-36 = -50

Comment: output is not -50, this is -78, -4-20-54=-78

Comment: This is usually not called a dot product but rather a **scalar triple product**: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product); [Mathinsight.org](https://mathinsight.org/scalar_triple_product).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your numpy arrays are `a`, `b`, and `c`, respectively:

```
>>> (a * b).dot(c)
-78
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [123]: a=np.array([1, 2, 3])
     ...: b=np.array([4, 5, 6])
     ...: c=np.array([-1, -2, -3])
```

Combine them into one array:

```
In [124]: arr = np.vstack((a,b,c))
In [125]: arr
Out[125]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [-1, -2, -3]])
```

Taking product down the columns, followed by a sum.

```
In [127]: np.prod(arr, axis=0)
Out[127]: array([ -4, -20, -54])
In [128]: np.sum(np.prod(arr, axis=0))
Out[128]: -78
```

or

```
np.sum(a*b*c)
```

Another approach

```
np.einsum('i,i,i', a, b, c)
```

Again this is the sum of all products.